# Como agrego una propiedad en un objeto mediante una funcion en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objeto, javascript-objeto

Necesito hacer una funcion que agregue una propiedad a un objeto vacio, quiero que la propiedad se llame myProperty y su valor sea true, lo estoy haciendo asi pero dice undefined:

```
    function addProperty(obj, key) 
{
 return obj.key = true;
}

var myObj = {};
addProperty(myObj, 'myProperty');
console.log(myObj.myProperty);
```

el output deberia ser: true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad en este caso `key` es un valor variable, de otro modo seria siempre una propiedad llamada 'key'

```
function addProperty(obj, key) 
{
 return obj[key] = true;
}
```

En otras palabras  `obj.key` equivale a `obj['key']`

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias aunque no entiendo mucho la logica si me funciona